# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=m}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} {k \choose m}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

By using generating functions and snake-oil I got to

[image]

Also what is the implication of $\sum \limits_ {k<={n}}$?

I am told that this is equivalent to:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to do that step, thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{k=m}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}=0, n>m\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540355/sum-k-mn-1k-binomnk-binomkm-0-nm-geq-0)

Answer (score 3):

It’s the binomial theorem,

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k\le n}\binom{n}ka^kb^{n-k}\;.$$

Now let $a=1+x$ and $b=-1$.

In this case taking the sum over $k\le n$ is equivalent to taking it from $k=0$ to $k=n$: by definition $\binom{n}k=0$ if $k<0$.

Comment: thanks a lot! I came across a similar question $\sum \limits_{k} {n \choose k} {x^k} {(1+y)^k}$ how would i apply the binomial theorem to this question.

Comment: @wallacetang: You’re welcome. Now that you’ve edited it, that’s clearly $\big(1+x(1+y)\big)^n$ by the binomial theorem, with $a=x(1+y)$ and $b=1$.

Comment: it comes out to be $(1+x+xy)^n$, im not sure how the xy term came to be