# Evaluate the sum for all positive integers n and m

Tags: binomial-theorem

$\suṃ̣_{k=m}^{n}  (-1)^k {n \choose k} {k \choose m}$ for all positive integers such that n > m.

My attempt, since k=m. I get $\suṃ̣_{k=m}^{n}  (-1)^k {n \choose k} {m \choose m} = \suṃ̣_{k=m}^{n}  (-1)^k {n \choose k}$.

What do I do from this step?

Comment: No, $k=m$ is only true for the first term of the sum, then the second term you have $k=m+1$ followed by $k=m+2$, and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum_{k=m}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}=0, n>m\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540355/sum-k-mn-1k-binomnk-binomkm-0-nm-geq-0)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276332/evaluate-sum-limits-k-mn-1k-n-choose-k-k-choose-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{k-m}
$$
to rewrite the sum as
$$
\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=m}^n (-1)^k\binom{n-m}{k-m}=
\binom{n}{m}(-1)^m\sum_{u=0}^{n-m}(-1)^{u}\binom{n-m}{u}
=\binom{n}{m}(-1)^m(1-1)^{n-m}=0
$$
where in the first equality we make the change of indices $u=k-m$ and in the penultimate equality we use the binomial theorem and the fact that $n>m$.